# Android - Make my app launchable from the Apps List and from "Share" menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an Activity, which I want to make launchable from Apps List and by choosing it in the "Share smth." menu. Here's a code of my Activity in AndroidManifest

---

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

But there's no that Activty in the Apps List and in the "Share" menu. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please read the documentation for `intent filters`.  BTW, because of this hack, `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize`, you probably have bugs in your code.  Try receiving a phone call whilst your app is running or put it in the background for a few hours then resume it.

Comment: It's hard to say from looking at the XML you posted. Post your Java codes.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 separate Intent filters: one for the launcher (so your app shows up in the list of available apps) and one to indicate that you are able to receive image files (so it shows up in the "share" list):

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```